# Can't code sign with distribution provision profile after renewing distribution certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile

I recently renewed my distribution certificate and added it to my laptop.  I re-created a distribution provision profile that uses the new certificate and added it to Xcode. The only issue is that now it can't find the correct distribution profile.  Per example, the App ID is 18FH128DBH.ApplicationName and the bundle ID set here is 18FH128DBH.ApplicationName. However, if I try to find the provision profile, it just reads:

ApplicationName - for Bundle Identifiers ('ApplicationName')
profile doesn't match bundle identifier '18FH128DBH.ApplicationName

So, I removed the bundle seed ID and it found the correct profile to sign with. I can build successfully from there.  However, when I try to submit to the App Store, I get an error saying that the 'Bundle identifier 'ApplicationName' differs from prior bundle identifier '18FH128DBH.ApplicationName'.  Not sure how I can rectify the issue; I've been working on this for several hours with no avail.

Any clue on why this is?

Answer (score 0):

These instructions might be a little bit outdated, but I've had a similar problem happen to me in the past and wrote this down for myself. I think the issue is that the keychain gets "out of whack". I can't promise this will work, because I honestly am not sure what causes the problem but this has worked for me in the past. Good luck!

Launch XCode
Open Window Organizer
Delete all provisioning profiles from your device
Delete all provisioning profiles under 'Development'
Log into the developer website
Click on 'Certificates' and Revoke your certificate
Launch 'Keychain Access' on your local desktop.
With the 'login' keychain selected
Delete all developer certificates
Delete all of your public/private keys
Close and restart 'Keychain Access'
Go back to the developer portal and request a new certificate (follow instructions)
Once the CSR has been uploaded and approved
Make sure that the new certificate is associated with the appropriate provisioning profiles.
Download and install the new certificate
Open XCode -> Organizer and add your device to the team provisioning portal
Go back to the developer portal and download and install the provisioning profile.
You should be good to go now to build and install to your device.